# How to look in previous column when pasting data

Tags: vba, excel, copy, duplicates

I have a code that allows me to look for duplicate values from a reference sheet and, if they are not duplicates, it will paste that different value into a "historical comment" sheet.  This is to keep track of comments I have made about a topic.  The comments change occasionally, and I want to keep a historical comment sheet to keep track of the past changes I have made.  I have a code that will look in the first sheet and search for duplicates and paste the unique values into this back sheet, but I was wondering if there was a way to have the code paste in the next column over if the current cell already has a value in it.  I just want to make sure that my code doesn't write over past historical comments.  Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyPasteHistorical()
Dim sht1Rng As Range, cell As Range

With Worksheets("AAG") '<-- reference Sheet1
    Set sht1Rng = .Range("I1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<-- set range with its column "I" cells containing constant (i.e. not formulas) values
End With

With Worksheets("Sheet2") '<-- reference Sheet2
    For Each cell In sht1Rng '<-- loop through Sheet1 range
        If cell.Value <> .Cells(cell.Row, "C") Then .Cells(cell.Row, "D") = cell.Value '<-- if sheet1 current cell content is different from Sheet2 column "C" cell content in the same row then write it in Sheet 2 column "D" corresponding row
    Next cell
End With
End Sub
```

I hope this makes sense and any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: Sure, you should look up "find next empty cell in sheet", you could do something like `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1`, or just `Offset()`.

Comment: thank you! would this go at the end of the code or somewhere in between two lines?  I apologize for the basic question, I'm just starting to learn VBA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version of your subroutine which will store the current value in the next column if it is different to the last value that had been stored:

```
Sub CopyPasteHistorical()
    Dim sht1Rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim lastCol As Long

    With Worksheets("AAG") '<-- reference Sheet1
        Set sht1Rng = .Range("I1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<-- set range with its column "I" cells containing constant (i.e. not formulas) values
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet2") '<-- reference Sheet2
        For Each cell In sht1Rng '<-- loop through Sheet1 range
            'determine last used column in row we are processing
            lastCol = .Cells(cell.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            If lastCol < 3 Then
                'if the last used column on the row is before column C
                'we need to store this value in column C
                .Cells(cell.Row, 3).Value = cell.Value
            ElseIf cell.Value <> .Cells(cell.Row, lastCol).Value Then
                'if the last value on the row is different to the current value
                'we need to store this value in the next column to the right
                .Cells(cell.Row, lastCol + 1).Value = cell.Value
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

---

And here is a version of your subroutine which will only store the current value if it has never been used before:

```
Sub CopyPasteHistorical()
    Dim sht1Rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim Col As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim blnMatched As Boolean

    With Worksheets("AAG") '<-- reference Sheet1
        Set sht1Rng = .Range("I1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<-- set range with its column "I" cells containing constant (i.e. not formulas) values
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet2") '<-- reference Sheet2
        For Each cell In sht1Rng '<-- loop through Sheet1 range
            'determine last used column in row we are processing
            lastCol = .Cells(cell.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            If lastCol < 3 Then
                'if the last used column on the row is before column C
                'we need to store this value in column C
                .Cells(cell.Row, 3).Value = cell.Value
            Else
                'see if this value has already been stored
                blnMatched = False
                For Col = 3 To lastCol
                    If cell.Value = .Cells(cell.Row, Col).Value Then
                        blnMatched = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
                'if the current value doesn't match any previous values
                'we need to store this value in the next column to the right
                If Not blnMatched Then
                    .Cells(cell.Row, lastCol + 1).Value = cell.Value
                End If
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure to understand your real aim, but you may want to try this

```
Sub CopyPasteHistorical2()
    Dim sht1Rng As Range, cell As Range

    With Worksheets("AAG") '<-- reference worksheet "AAG"
        Set sht1Rng = .Range("I1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<-- set range with its column "I" cells containing constant (i.e. not formulas) values
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet2") '<-- reference Worksheet "Sheet2"
        For Each cell In sht1Rng '<-- loop through Sheet1 range
            If cell.Value <> .Cells(cell.Row, "C") Then .Cells(cell.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, IIf(.Cells(cell.Row, "D") = "", 3, 1)) = cell.Value '<-- if sheet1 current cell content is different from Sheet2 column "C" cell content in the same row then write it in Sheet 2 corresponding row first free cell from column "D" rightwards
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```